# losing subclass fields when serializing in django?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-taggit

I see baffling and what seems flatout bad behavior in serializing django objects. For example, I have models:

```
class MyTag(TagBase):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class MyMpttTag(MPTTModel, MyTag):
    parent      = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        parent_attr         = 'parent'
```

which means that MyMpptTag has fields of `name, slug, user, parent`. But when I do `serializers.serialize('json', MyMpptTag.object.all())`, I get:
[{"fields": {"lft": 1, "level": 0, "tree_id": 29, "parent": null, "rght": 2}, "model": "index.mymptttag", "pk": 45}...]

Why would I lose `name, slug, and user`, and how do I get them back? Thank you

Comment: If `MyTag` is not an abstract class, serializing will result in at least 2 typw of objects (with same primary key). One of them will be from `MyMpttTag` model and one from `MyTag` model (there may be more if `TagBase` and it's parents are also non-abstract).

Comment: this makes more sense, so the normal behavior is good, but if you intended on using the class only as a subclass I should put abstract=True.  will this cause any significant issues in migrating after I make is an abstract?

Comment: TagBase is an abstract within django-taggit

Comment: yes there was bad design when I did not declare abstract. I cannot accept your answer since it is in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that model design, you will have 2 tables in database:

- `yourapp_mytag` that will have primary key column (normal auto-increment column), all columns inherited from `TagBase` (as long as `TagBase` is abstract) and column user - foreign key to model User
- `yourapp_mymptttag` tht will have primary key column that is also foreign key to `MyTag` model and columns for mptt. There won't be any columns inherited from `MyTag`.

That means: there are no columns inherited from `MyTag` in model `MyMpttTag`, there are only references to actual columns in `MyTag`.

In serialization there will be 2 type of objects: `MyMpttTag` and `MyTag`.

Comment: the migrations were nasty, but subclassing MyTag as abstract solved it